# Semantically correct html tag for "Theorem"?

Tags: html

On my web page, I present mathematical theorems and the page design is very close to the style used in academic math papers (LaTeX).
The heading structure might be as follows:

**Geometry**

*Plane geometry*

Theorem.

We have that a²+b²=c².

Question: Should I use the `<h3>` tag to enclose `Theorem`,
or should I style it with `<span>`, or `<b>`?

In some sense, it acts as a small heading for a section, but there might be several headings with the exact same title (Theorem) on the page, which might be considered strange for a SEO perspective.

Comment: What about ```<article>``` tag ...?

Comment: No, should it be <h3>Theorem</h3> or <b>Theorem</b> ?

Comment: The whole content of the paper should be inside an `<article>` tag because all of the paper's content including the title are part of the distributable.  Perhaps not the discipline.

Comment: @DavidKlinge Sure, but that is not what the question is asking.

Answer (score 2):

You may use multiple `<h3>` tags. Go with makes the most sense semantically. If "Theorem" is being used as a section header, then use the `<h3>` (make sure you're not skipping one or more section header elements) as many times as you need to.

See the examples used at [MDN - The HTML Section Heading elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements), it's not a stretch to see your desired use in their examples.